# Postgresql: extract number before given substring

Tags: postgresql, substring

I want to create variable: Number which extract numbers before $

```
Name      | Number
abc1/12 $ | 12
12av 12$  | 12
114$-bgv  | 114
```

I have a query:

```
select Name, substring(Name FROM '%#"[0-9]+#"$%' FOR '#') as Number
from table;
```

But it returns:

```
Name      | Number
abc1/12 $ | 
12av 12$  | 2
114$-bgv  | 4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `substring(Name from '(\d+)\$')`

Comment: i updated the problem - please check again.

Comment: It's simple: `'(\d+)\s*\$'`

Comment: it does not work. and additionaly if I want to extract from pattern 'number+'gb' (i.e. 15gb) instead of number+$ (i.e. 15$) it returns 'invalid escape \ sequence'; using postgresql 9.2

Comment: "It does not work" is a bad description of the problem. And be more specific about what exactly you want to extract. Additionally it seems that you unfamiliar with regular expressions (I am unfamiliar too :) Learn more about its syntax. In short: dollar sign '$' should be escaped by slash because it means EOL in regular expressions. However `gb` is a simple substring so it is not needed to be escaped: `'(\d+)\s*gb`. Thats why you getting 'invalid escape sequence' error. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select
  (regexp_matches(Name,  '^(.*[^\d]+){0,1}(\d+)\$'))[2] as Number
from (
  select 'abc1/12$' as Name
  union select '12av 12$'
  union select 'bgv-114$'
  union select '124$'
) t
```

Or with `substring()`

```
select
  coalesce(substring(Name FROM '.*[^\d]+(\d+)\$'), '') ||
  coalesce(substring(Name FROM '^(\d+)\$'), '') as Number
from (
  select 'abc1/12$' as Name
  union select '12av 12$'
  union select 'bgv-114$'
  union select '124$'
) t
```

Comment: This does not handle '5$ foo'

Comment: More transparent query is with using `regexp_matches()`.